# Incompatible types: 'Byte' and 'String'

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, valueconverter

I get the compiler error *Incompatible types: 'Byte' and 'String'* on the following function:

```
IntToStr(DiskSize('F:\'))
```

I want to convert the disk size to a string. How to solve this problem?

Comment: You could easily have answered this question yourself by simply having a look at [the documentation](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/SysUtils_DiskSize.html) of `DiskSize`. After all, if you haven't used a funcion before, you always consult the documentation before you use it, especially if you don't know how to use it, like in this case.

Comment: I agree with you, but I am a newer so, I will some easy problems. I will try to read the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

The argument for `DiskSize` is a byte (hence, not a `string`) where 0 is current drive, 1=A, 2=B etc. so for drive F you want `DiskSize(6)`, or more generally a function to do this would be:

```
function DiskSizeL(DriveLetter: Char): Int64;
begin
  DriveLetter := UpCase(DriveLetter);
  Result := DiskSize(1 + Ord(DriveLetter) - Ord('A'));
end;
```

You would want to check that the char was in the range A to Z though etc.

Comment: What means current driver?

Comment: The drive that the current working directory resides on (Use GetCurrentDir to find it)

Comment: function DiskSizeL(DriveLetter: Char): Int64;
begin
  DriveLetter := UpCase(DriveLetter);
  Result := DiskSize(1 + Ord(DriveLetter) - Ord('A'));
DiskSizeL('F')

still doesn't work.
end;

Comment: Before the edits that others have made (that have substantially improved the code in the answer - thank you NGLN and David Heffernan) it did work, and I see no reason why those edits have changed anything. What doesn't work? What error message do you get? As far as I can tell IntToStr(DiskSizeL('F')) will return a string representation of the size in bytes of the disk F.

Comment: If the answer has worked could you accept it? Click the tick next at the top left of the answer. Thanks.